# Callback function after setTimeout

Tags: javascript, callback

I'm not getting the desired results with this below callback. I'm trying to write a simple callback which executes after setTimeout is done, however I'm seeing the callback function execution first followed by the actual function.

What I'm missing here? to get the results as below.

```
doing my homework Maths
finished my homework
```

Here is the code I'm trying to run.

```
function doHomeWork(subject, callback){
setTimeout(function(){console.log("doing my homework:", subject)},500)
callback();
}

doHomeWork("Maths", function(){console.log("finished my homework");});
```

Comment: You need to place the `callback()` call inside the timeout! Put it after the `console.log` call. Currently you are starting the timer with `setTimeout()`, then immediately calling the `callback()`.

Comment: ^^ using proper indentation and line breaks makes the mistake easier to spot: https://pastebin.com/WWQHSPN9 (Voting to close as typo/non-repro/not-useful-to-others-in-future)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `setTimeout()` a browser callback is registered. It does not mean subsequent statements will also get executed later. They will execute immediately after calling function `setTimeout()`. Only the function parameter you have passed will be called by `setTimeout()` when the timeout occurs. So, if the callback needs to be executed after `setTimeout()` parameterized function. It is better to move that call inside `setTimeout()` function parameter. So, the code will look like

```
setTimeout(function() {
    //Your stuff
    callback();
}, 500);
```

Comment: You can probably assume that the console.log() in his timeout function is supposed to go before your setTimeout() call.

Comment: *"When you call setTimeout() a separate thread starts"* No, that's not correct at all. The browser adds a timer to its list of timers. The browser queues a task in the thread's job queue and the thread picks it up as part of its job loop.

Comment: From the JavaScript perspective, the timeout function is a new thread, it could become a multi-threaded application, if both threads ran longer. That it then becomes serialized in a single threaded engine is a different matter.

Answer (score 4):

You missunderstand the usage of `setTimeout`.

The correct implementation of what you are asking for is:

```
function doHomeWork(subject, callback){
    setTimeout(callback,500);
    console.log("doing my homework:", subject)
}

doHomeWork("Maths", function(){console.log("finished my homework");});
```

When you invoke `doHomeWork` it you do two things (two lines of code):
1. Say the browser to add a the callback as a new task to be executed after 500ms.
2. Print console.log(...)

After 500ms, the browser will add a new task with the callback that will be invoked.

Answer (score 1):

#### Easier for a Callback beginner without own function

```
setTimeout(() => {
console.log('finish homework')
}, 500);
console.log('start homework')
```

Output:

```
start hw
finish hw
```

The queue will go through the code including *start hw* , and then later execute the timeout-code inside `setTimeout()` with *finish hw*. The reason for this upside-down time behaviour is that inside `function setTimeout(callback){ ... callback() ...}` the `callback()` function is called which is later than the execution of the main thread which is written by you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to wait before that callback especially if callback is API call then create a separate function and return resolved promise  from inside a `setTimeout` from that function, and use async await to await that wait function before doing API calls.

If you didn't get something then you can ask for further explanation.